# Efficiency of binary search and improvements

Tags: algorithm, c, binary-search

Below you can see my binary search method, and as a relatively new programmer I am looking for any suggestions on how it could be improved.

```
bool found = false;
int min = 0;
int max = 9;
int avg;
int anArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

int userNumber;

printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10:\n");
scanf("%d", &userNumber);

while(!found){
    avg = (min+max)/2;
    if(anArray[avg]==userNumber){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    if(anArray[avg]<userNumber)
        min = avg+1;
    else if(anArray[avg]>userNumber)
        max = avg-1;
    if( (min==max) && (anArray[max]!=userNumber) )
        break;
}
if(found)
    printf("The number is in index [%d]\n", avg);
else
    printf("Number not found\n");
```

Comment: Needs more curly braces! =)

Comment: Could you include the whole function, with it's name and parameters? It will be easier to review with more context.

Comment: @Mat'sMug whats wrong with the curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### While loop termination

The while loop condition is:

> ```
> while(!found) {
> ```

But when you find your answer, you already do a `break`.  Therefore, the while loop condition could just be:

```
while (1) {
```

But there's more.  This statement here is not quite right:

> ```
> if( (min==max) && (anArray[max]!=userNumber) )
>     break;
> ```

First of all, it is possible that `min` could actually go beyond `max`.  For example, if originally `min` is 6, `max` is 7, and `avg` is 6, then it could be the case that `max` becomes 5 afterwards.  So you really need to check if `min > max` and break when that happens.

Secondly, if `min == max`, there's no need to do an extra equality check and break.  You can just loop around one more time.

Putting that all together, I would actually remove that whole if statement and change your while loop to:

```
while (min <= max) {
    avg = (min+max) / 2;
    if (anArray[avg] == userNumber) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    if (anArray[avg] < userNumber)
        min = avg+1;
    else
        max = avg-1;
}
```

### Unnecessary if

Notice I also removed the check for `anArray[avg] > userNumber` because at that point, it wasn't equal or less than, so it had to be greater than.

Comment: Nice solution. I like the elimination of that unnecessary if statement as well, I should have spotted that.